# Switch statement throws error in TypeScript when attempting to handle enum values

Tags: typescript, loops, enums

I'm using the following while and switch-case loops. I'm trying to handle all the different enum values in the `constants.Sides` enum.

// EDIT Constants is imported at the top of the file.

```js
import * as constants from '../constants'

// ... other code not included

let crossedSide: constants.Sides | undefined;
let loopGuard = 0;

while ((crossedSide = this.hasCrossedBorder()) && loopGuard < 2) {
  loopGuard += 1;

  switch (crossedSide) {
    case constants.Sides.TOP: { // THE ERROR HAPPENS HERE
      this.velocity.y = -this.velocity.y;
      break;
    }
    case constants.Sides.RIGHT: {
      this.velocity.x = -this.velocity.x;
      break;
    }
    case constants.Sides.BOTTOM: {
      this.velocity.y = -this.velocity.y;
      break;
    }
    case constants.Sides.LEFT: {
      this.velocity.x = -this.velocity.x;
      break;
    }
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

The enum is defined in `constants/index.ts` as follows:

```js
export enum Sides {
  TOP,
  RIGHT,
  BOTTOM,
  LEFT,
}
```

However, an error is thrown at the `constants.Sides.TOP` switch-case option:

> Type 'Sides.TOP' is not comparable to type 'Sides.RIGHT | Sides.BOTTOM | Sides.LEFT'.

Comment: how do you define `constants` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in TypeScript handling the first enum value, i.e. `TOP`, as 0 i.e. falsy. This is why the while condition returns only the remaining three truthy enum values: `RIGHT`, `BOTTOM` and `LEFT`.

The issue is fixed by adding another value to the enumeration like so:

```js
export enum Sides {
  NONE = 0,
  TOP,
  RIGHT,
  BOTTOM,
  LEFT,
}
```

This way also the `TOP` value will be truthy.